# Menu items suddenly are displayed all over the page

Tags: menus, bug, menu-order

Strange things are happening :( When you take a look at the site:
www.handelbijvanandel.nl you will see that all menu- and submenu items are shown on the page.

At first I didn't pay much attention to it and did a backup restore.
This solves the issue for a little while, but then the problem pops-up again :(

Any ideas where to look?

Best regards,
Hielke

Comment: Hello Hielke, best place to start would be in Appearance > Menus to make sure the menu is set up correctly. If it is you'd need to check the code in the template from which the menu is being called. It looks as though the menu isn't nested for one reason or another.

Comment: Thanks Kieran! That solved the problem. The strange thing is, that I re-ordered a couple of items, saved the menu, and voila, everything is back as normal!

Comment: No problem. I know in the past it's happened to me when I've changed a theme. Sometimes the menu appears fine in the Appearance section but you need to save it again (or reset it's position) and it works again.